# Help with the difference in the meaning of the phrases

Tags: meaning, differences, phrase-meaning

What difference is between these phrases?

1. be going to do something
2. be out to do something
3. intend to do something

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are "going to do something" it means that you will do the "something" in the future.
2. You are currently out/away doing the "something" in the present.
3. You have intentions/plans to do the "something" in the future.